# Get number of bytes/packets in and out on a specific TCP/UDP port

Tags: linux, tcp, proc

**I don't want to use `tcpdumps` or `wireshark`**

So, is there any way to get number bytes/packets transmitted and revived on a specific port. We can get in `/proc/<PID>/net/dev` of process which is listening on specific port. But I have to parse `ss -tupn` to get the `pids` of desired process(Which is LISTEN/ESTAB on desired port) and then goto `/proc/<PID>/net/dev` which is long process. Besides, processes like `apache` runs on multiple `PIDs`, so I have to read all PID's `/proc/<PID>/net/dev`?? or should I consider single process?

Instead of doing like above, is there any way or `command` to get number of packets/bytes that `in` and `out` of specific port (easy and efficiently)

Comment: use netfilter with `iptables`

Comment: @Ipor Sircer Thanks for the comment. I dont want manipulate the `iptable` rules on the production server.